# What is wrong with this IDLE python code?

Tags: tensorflow

I ran the code on this site in IDLE python https://sites.google.com/view/dailycoding00/main/%EC%95%8C%ED%8C%8C%EC%98%A4-%ED%95%99%EC%8A%B5
but it had an error

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Windows\system32\python", line 343, in <module>
    ex = MyApp()
  File "C:\Windows\system32\python", line 16, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "C:\Windows\system32\python", line 38, in initUI
    self.board_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(board_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xr4y3u3_\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

what does it mean?
code is
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import cv2
import time
import tensorflow as tf

class MyApp(QWidget):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    load_model_path = 'model/model.ckpt'

    #
    board_size = 15
    self.game_end = 0
    self.board_size = board_size
    self.board = np.zeros([board_size,board_size])
    self.board_history = np.zeros([board_size,board_size])
    self.cnt = 1


    time_now = time.gmtime(time.time())
    self.save_name = str(time_now.tm_year) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_mon) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_mday) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_hour) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_min) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_sec) + '.txt'
    self.save_name_png = str(time_now.tm_year) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_mon) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_mday) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_hour) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_min) + '_' + str(time_now.tm_sec) + '.png'

    
    # read image in numpy array (using cv2)
    board_cv2 = cv2.imread('c:\\omok_v1.0/source/board_1515.png')
    self.board_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(board_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    white_ball = cv2.imread('c:\\omok_v1.0/source/white.png')
    self.white_ball = cv2.cvtColor(white_ball, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    black_ball = cv2.imread('c:\\omok_v1.0/source/black.png')
    self.black_ball = cv2.cvtColor(black_ball, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # numpy to QImage
    height, width, channel = self.board_cv2.shape
    bytesPerLine = 3 * width
    qImg_board = QImage(self.board_cv2.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)

    self.player = 1 # 1: 흑  / 2: 백
    x = 0
    y = 0

    self.lbl_img = QLabel()
    self.lbl_img.setPixmap(QPixmap(qImg_board))

    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl_img)
    self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    # load AI model
    self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, board_size*board_size])
    X_img = tf.reshape(self.X, [-1, board_size, board_size, 1])
     
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7,7,1,64], stddev=0.1))
    L1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X_img, W1, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME') 
    L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)
    #L1 = tf.nn.dropout(L1, keep_prob=keep_prob)
     
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,64,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L2 = tf.nn.conv2d(L1, W2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L2 = tf.nn.relu(L2)
    #L2 = tf.nn.dropout(L2, keep_prob=keep_prob)
     
    W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L3 = tf.nn.conv2d(L2, W3, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L3 = tf.nn.relu(L3)
    #L3 = tf.nn.dropout(L3, keep_prob=keep_prob)

    W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L4 = tf.nn.conv2d(L3, W4, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L4 = tf.nn.relu(L4)
    #L4 = tf.nn.dropout(L4, keep_prob=keep_prob)


    W5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L5 = tf.nn.conv2d(L4, W5, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L5 = tf.nn.relu(L5)
    #L5 = tf.nn.dropout(L5, keep_prob=keep_prob)


    W6 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L6 = tf.nn.conv2d(L5, W6, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L6 = tf.nn.relu(L6)

    W7 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L7 = tf.nn.conv2d(L6, W7, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L7 = tf.nn.relu(L7)

    W8 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L8 = tf.nn.conv2d(L7, W8, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L8 = tf.nn.relu(L8)

    W9 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,32,32], stddev = 0.1))
    L9 = tf.nn.conv2d(L8, W9, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    L9 = tf.nn.relu(L9)
    #L6 = tf.nn.dropout(L6, keep_prob=keep_prob)

    L9 = tf.reshape(L9, [-1, board_size * board_size * 32])

     
    W10 = tf.get_variable("W10", shape=[board_size * board_size * 32, board_size*board_size],initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

    b10 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([board_size * board_size]))
    self.logits =tf.matmul(L9,W10) + b10
    

    self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

    self.sess = tf.Session()
    self.saver.restore(self.sess, load_model_path)

    
    self.setWindowTitle('오목 시뮬레이션')
    self.move(100, 100)
    self.resize(500,500)
    self.show()


def game_play(self, board_img, ball, pos_x, pos_y, turn):
    #human

    ball_size = ball.shape[0]
    step_size = 56
    off_set = 10

    # ]
    if pos_x < step_size/2+off_set+1 or pos_y < step_size/2+off_set+1:
        print('그곳에는 둘 수 없습니다')

    elif pos_x > step_size*self.board_size+step_size/2+off_set or pos_y > step_size*self.board_size+step_size/2+off_set:
        print('그곳에는 둘 수 없습니다')

    else:

        step_x = round((pos_x - off_set)/step_size)
        step_y = round((pos_y - off_set)/step_size)

        if self.board[step_x-1,step_y-1] != 0: # 이미 돌이 있을때
            print('그곳에는 둘 수 없습니다')

        else:
            self.board[step_x-1,step_y-1] = turn
            self.board_history[step_x-1,step_y-1] = self.cnt
            self.cnt = self.cnt + 1
            
            x_step = step_size*step_x-round(step_size/2) + off_set
            y_step = step_size*step_y-round(step_size/2) + off_set
            
            board_img[x_step:x_step+ball_size,y_step:y_step+ball_size] = ball

            # 
           if self.game_rule(self.board, turn):
                self.game_end = 1

                print('게임이 끝났습니다.')

                board_img = cv2.cvtColor(board_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                

                print('축하합니다 당신이 승리 하였습니다')


                              
    return board_img

def sigmoid(self, x):
    return 1 / (1 +np.exp(-x))

def find_max(self, result_mat):

    max = 0
    max_x = 0 
    max_y = 0

    for i in range(self.board_size):
        for j in range(self.board_size):
            if result_mat[i,j] > max:
                max = result_mat[i,j]
                max_x = i
                max_y = j

    result_mat[max_x,max_y] = 0
    return result_mat, max_x, max_y       



def mousePressEvent(self, e):

    x = e.x()
    y = e.y()
    if self.game_end == 0:

        # 

        self.board_cv2 = self.game_play(self.board_cv2, self.black_ball, y, x, 1)
       
        save_name =  'result/' + str(self.cnt) + "board_black.png"
        save_name_w = 'result/' + str(self.cnt) + "board_white.png"
        save_name_pred = 'result/' + str(self.cnt) + "board_pred.png"

        

        # 
        input_X = self.board.flatten()/2
        result = self.sess.run(self.logits, feed_dict={self.X: input_X[None,:]})
        result_mat = self.sigmoid(result).reshape([self.board_size,self.board_size])

        heat_map = cv2.resize(result_mat*255, (500, 500))            
        result_mat, max_x, max_y = self.find_max(result_mat)

        save_image = cv2.resize(self.board_cv2, (500, 500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        save_image = cv2.cvtColor(save_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        #save_image[:,:,0] = save_image[:,:,0] + heat_map

        cv2.imwrite(save_name, save_image)
        cv2.imwrite(save_name_pred, heat_map)


        # 
        while self.board[max_x,max_y] !=0:
            print('AI 거긴 둘 수 없다')
            result_mat, max_x, max_y = self.find_max(result_mat)


        self.board[max_x,max_y] = 2 # 인공지능은 항상 2값 / 사람은 1값으로 표현
        self.board_history[max_x,max_y] = self.cnt
        self.cnt = self.cnt + 1

        ball_size = self.white_ball.shape[0]
        step_size = 56
        off_set = 10
        x_step = step_size*(max_x+1)-round(step_size/2) + off_set
        y_step = step_size*(max_y+1)-round(step_size/2) + off_set
        self.board_cv2[x_step:x_step+ball_size,y_step:y_step+ball_size] = self.white_ball

         
        save_image = cv2.resize(self.board_cv2, (500, 500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        save_image = cv2.cvtColor(save_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)   
        cv2.imwrite(save_name_w, save_image)
        #self.board_history[step_x-1,step_y-1] = self.cnt
        
        #self.board_cv2 = self.game_play(self.board_cv2, self.white_ball, y, x, 2)
            
       
        height, width, channel = self.board_cv2.shape
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        qImg_board = QImage(self.board_cv2.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.lbl_img.setPixmap(QPixmap(qImg_board))



def game_rule(self, board, player): # 추후 오목 국룰 (렌주룰) 도입 예정

    game_result = 0
    diag_line = np.zeros(5)
    
    # ●●●●●
    for i_idx in range(len(board)):
        for j_idx in range(len(board)-4):
            p1 = (board[i_idx,j_idx:j_idx+5] == player)
            
            if p1.sum() == 5:
                #print('player ', player, ' win')
                game_result = 1
                return game_result
                #print(board)

    

    for i_idx in range(len(board)-4):
        for j_idx in range(len(board)):
            p1 = (board[i_idx:i_idx+5,j_idx] ==player)
            
            if p1.sum() == 5:
                #print('player ', player, ' win')
                game_result = 1
                return game_result
                #print(board)
    
    # 
    for i_idx in range(len(board)-4):
        for j_idx in range(len(board)-4):
            diag_line[0] = board[i_idx+0,j_idx+0]
            diag_line[1] = board[i_idx+1,j_idx+1]
            diag_line[2] = board[i_idx+2,j_idx+2]
            diag_line[3] = board[i_idx+3,j_idx+3]
            diag_line[4] = board[i_idx+4,j_idx+4]    
      
            p1 = (diag_line == player)
            
            if p1.sum() == 5:
                #print('player ', player, ' win')
                game_result = 1
                return game_result
                #print(board)

    #
    for i_idx in range(len(board)-4):
        for j_idx in range(len(board)-4):
            diag_line[0] = board[i_idx+4,j_idx+0]
            diag_line[1] = board[i_idx+3,j_idx+1]
            diag_line[2] = board[i_idx+2,j_idx+2]
            diag_line[3] = board[i_idx+1,j_idx+3]
            diag_line[4] = board[i_idx+0,j_idx+4]    
      
            p1 = (diag_line == player)
            
            if p1.sum() == 5:
                
                game_result = 1
                return game_result
        
    return game_result

def save_history(self):


    

    result=np.array(self.board_history).flatten()
    f = open(self.save_name, 'w')


    f.write(np.array2string(result))
    f.close()
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyApp()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please include all code in your question.

Comment: My code is on that site.

Comment: Code should be pasted here, not in an external website. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: oops sorry. I didn't know